# Extract the dataset from the compressed .tar.gz file

Tags: python

When I was running below code to extract the dataset from the compressed .tar.gz file, I got the error below. The maybe_extract function tries to extract data from the .tar.gz file. Could someone tell me what's wrong here?

Code:

```
num_classes = 10
np.random.seed(133)

def maybe_extract(filename, force=False):
    root = os.path.splitext(os.path.splitext(filename)[0])[0]  # remove .tar.gz
    if os.path.isdir(root) and not force:
        # You may override by setting force=True.
        print('%s already present - Skipping extraction of %s.' % (root, filename))
    else:
        print('Extracting data for %s. This may take a while. Please wait.' % root)
        tar = tarfile.open(filename)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        tar.extractall()
        tar.close()
    data_folders = [os.path.join(root, d) for d in sorted(os.listdir(root)) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, d))]
    if len(data_folders) != num_classes:
        raise Exception('Expected %d folders, one per class. Found %d instead.' % (num_classes, len(data_folders)))
    print(data_folders)
    return data_folders

train_folders = maybe_extract(train_filename)
test_folders = maybe_extract(test_filename)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-e73ef7c66cdb> in <module>()
     19     return data_folders
     20 
---> 21 train_folders = maybe_extract(train_filename)
     22 test_folders = maybe_extract(test_filename)

<ipython-input-13-e73ef7c66cdb> in maybe_extract(filename, force)
      3 
      4 def maybe_extract(filename, force=False):
----> 5     root = os.path.splitext(os.path.splitext(filename)[0])[0]  # remove .tar.gz
      6     if os.path.isdir(root) and not force:
      7         # You may override by setting force=True.

/Users/a/anaconda/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc in splitext(p)
     96 
     97 def splitext(p):
---> 98     return genericpath._splitext(p, sep, altsep, extsep)
     99 splitext.__doc__ = genericpath._splitext.__doc__
    100 

/Users/a/anaconda/lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc in _splitext(p, sep, altsep, extsep)
     97     leading dots.  Returns "(root, ext)"; ext may be empty."""
     98 
---> 99     sepIndex = p.rfind(sep)
    100     if altsep:
    101         altsepIndex = p.rfind(altsep)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Comment: Looks like the traceback suggests `filename` is not correct.

Comment: `os.path.splitext(os.path.splitext(filename)[0])[0]` tries to split the file name and extension by further calling an internal/protected method called `_splitext(p, sep, ...`  which tries to find the first occurrence of a separator (full stop, I presume) starting from the right/end of the string `p`: `sepIndex = p.rfind(sep)`. This fails because `p` == `None` at this point in execution. Could it be because you have two full stops in the file names; i.e. name.tar.gz?

Comment: Thanks guys for help :) Yes, I had a typo in the filename, I should've been more careful..